# SwiftUI - How to animate button onto screen?

Tags: animation, swiftui

I've got a button in SwiftUI that appears on a view depending on the count of an array, like this:

```
@State var arr ...

if arr.count > 0 {
  Button("click me!") {
    ...
  }
  .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
}
```

I want to animate the button to slide up from the bottom of the screen when the array count goes above 0, rather than it just abruptly appearing on the screen.

I tried the following lines: `.transition(.slide)` followed by `.animation(.spring(), value: arr.count)`, but these seemingly had no effect. How can I accomplish this animation?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The modifier `.transition()` works, you can check it in the example below. Are you sure that you are changing your `@State` variable using `withAnimation { }`?

This example slides both buttons up:

```
struct Example: View {
    
    @State private var array = [0, 1, 2]
    let trigger = 2
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                withAnimation {
                    array.append(1)
                }
            } label: {
                Text("Counter \(String(array.count))")
            }
            .padding()
            
            if array.count > trigger {
                Button("Click me!") {
                    print("Do nothing")
                }
                .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .bottom)
                .transition(.move(edge: .bottom))
                .padding()
            }
        }
    }
```

*(edited to use array.count as an example, removed transition from first button)*

Comment: when i tap the component that updates the array, it actually calls a function that contains: `withAnimation {arr.append(...)}` I'm not sure if that's correct? In your example you have `.transition(.slide)` on your button that updates the counter, I'm not sure where I would put that on mine.

Comment: The transition in the Button that updates the counter is not necessary, you can remove it. The important thing is to maintain the transition in the "Click me" button, which is what you want to achieve. I edited the code above also to use array, and it still works. Make sure your whole function is wrapped by `withAnimation()`, not just the line that changes the state variable; keep this func inside the view, not in an outside class or struct. I hope it works.